# Geth private testnet: what's wrong?

Tags: go-ethereum, mining, testnets, ethminer

I have downloaded geth and ethminer, and started running a testnet with 2 nodes - 1 mining and the other not. Here's my (noobish) problems:

1. If I submit a txn to my non-mining node, it won't get processed by
   the mining node even though both nodes are peers. Does it mean that
   only txns that are submitted to a mining node will be propagated to
   other mining nodes and get settled?
2. I tried to hook up my ethminer (1.4.x) to one of the nodes and
       perform gpu mining, but it either crashes my nvidia card (with 2MB
       mem) or just mine with 0 H/s. thoughout the trial the node seemed to
       recognize that something is trying to mine for it (eth.mining ==
       true and it says the next block is committed to be mined). Why does
       the ethminer instance keep producing 0 hashrate (I am actually
       ignoring the gpu crashing issue since it gets 0 H/s even with cpu
       mining)?

Comment: No, it's not normal if your second node is mining, but from your second point I understand that you can't mine. Can you clarify, is your second node mining successfully or not?

Comment: yes, second node can mine. I'm limited to mine with only 1 node by my DAG, which seems to disallow concurrent access by >1 nodes and I was fine with it until I discover that txns submitted to my 2nd non-mining node couldn't be settled. I restarted both nodes and switched to mine with the 2nd node, which mined and settled my resubmitted txn. That's how i conclude that only txns submitted to my mining node can be settled.

Comment: Did you figure out why it happend ?

Comment: haven't figured that out, and I sort of given up gpu mining and just play with cpu instead for point #2, and just live with the behavior described in point #1.

Answer (score 1):

Transactions may be dropped for reasons not related to mining. Make sure your transaction is propagated between nodes.

- check out the logs,
- check minimum gas price of the nodes (`--gasprice` option),
- check gas price of the transaction,
- check the nonce of the transaction.

Comment: In my case, i am quite positive that the txns never get propagated to other nodes as they never appear in the logs of the peer nodes

Answer (score 1):

I have had a similar experience, after fiddling with some of the geth flags the non-mining node's transactions started getting distributed. I'm not sure about this and I know it sounds wierd, but try removing/adding --nodiscover?

Comment: tried but no luck..

Comment: any update on this @coeniebeyers